# Google Speech API Asynchronous Speech Recognition в Андроид приложении

Tags: android, асинхронность, google-speech-recognition

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой когда нужно отправить аудиофайл, чтобы конвертировать его в текст, используя данную библиотеку. Когда создаем переменную OperationFuture  response - дженерик просит - “Make ‘LongRunningRecognizeResponse’ implement ‘com.google.protobuf.Message’.

Здесь пример со Streaming Speech Recognition https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech.

Если имплементировать интерфейс "Message", это приводит к ошибке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Кажется, Message - это класс а не интерфейс. И тогда его нужно расширить (extends), а не имплементировать...

Comment: Я специально добавил 2-ой скриншот, где видно, что я имплементировал интерфейс Message... Однако это не решает проблемы, возможно нужно как то заново сгенерировать .proto файлы, буду рад если подскажите как...

Comment: Ну так я же вам и говорю, что класс нельзя имплементировать. Его можно только наследовать. Проблема в том, что Message - это класс, а не интерфейс. Тут конечно есть проблема в том, что вы уже расширяете другой класс, а в java нет множественного наследования... Может быть, вы как-то могли бы обойтись без этого другого класса?

Comment: Проблема ведь в том что это классы из библиотеки, я их вообще не должен изменять. Единственное, я предполагаю, что должен сгенерировать .proto файлы, но не понимаю как это сделать.